# Does "Intel® Virtualization Technology" provide advantages for a desktop user?

Tags: hardware-virtualization

I was [reading](http://lwn.net/Articles/253361/) on virtualization and the associated costs. For servers or people, running VMs, there is apparent an advantage in a CPU with hardware virtualization support.

*But what about the average desktop user, who runs only a single OS - be it for gaming, work or whatever?* The [i3](http://ark.intel.com/products/90728/Intel-Core-i3-6300T-Processor-4M-Cache-3_30-GHz), for example, is far from gaming processor, but supports the technology.

Comment: If you are not using planning to utilize the feature then it does not serve a purpose.

Comment: Having an IOMMU might prevent certain DMA attacks.

Comment: It might on a guest OS but it wouldn't do much on the host OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you wanna do with it.
The virtualization technology allows you to run Virtal Machines. Virtual machines are like an OS (guest), that runs on top of another OS (host).
It also allows you to run virtualization-based security features. They aren't very useful to the average user, but, they can prevent attacks.
However, be aware that both the CPU and the Motherboard have to support virtualization.